# App Engine - PHP env - 500 error while sending email

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am planning to send GCP cost to stakeholders. I am using app engine to host and send an email.

> https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automated-email-cloud-billing-summary

I am using gcloudshell. I am getting below error.

> Error: 0.0.0.1:52050 [500]: /?authuser=0&environment_name=default - Uncaught Error: Class 'google\appengine\api\mail\Message' not found in /home/project/billingemails/index.php:39
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/project/billingemails/index.php on line 39'''

Code:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Auth;
    
    use Google\Auth\Credentials\GCECredentials;
    use google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService;
    use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
    use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;
    
    
    // Variables holding your values, replace before deploying
    $datatable = "projectid.billing_data.gcp_billing_export_v1_000000_000000_000000";
    $toemail = "gcpbilling@domain.com";
    $fromemail = "your@domain.com";
    
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
    
    try {
            $mailmsg = new Message();
            $mailmsg->setSender($fromemail);
            $mailmsg->addTo($toemail);
            $mailmsg->setSubject('GCP Billing Summary');
            $mailmsg->setTextBody($message);
            $mailmsg->send();
            printf('<br>---Mail sent successfully!---<br>');
    }
    catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            printf('<br>---Error occurred, could not send email---<br>');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: updated the vendor package:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk

Comment: Hi @rishi could you please indicate which line is the 39? As per the stack trace, the error seems to be on this line and due to the fact that your code is not complete as in the sample, it's not possible to identify the differences between your code and the one for the tutorial. Besides that, did you make sure to have a class called `Message` in your path `google\appengine\api\mail\`? This is another error being showed in your code.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?  App Engine has the `mail` API available for 5.5, but those APIs are no longer used in 7.  You would need to use a different API to send mail

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel line 39 is $mailmsg = new Message(); i was missing the class called Message. So i update the class manually on gcloudshell and its working now. I user PHP 5.5

Comment: Great to hear it helped @rishi can I post my comment as an answer, so you can accept and upvote it as the right solution?

Comment: Hi @rishi I have posted it as an answer, as it fixed your issue. Please, consider upvoting/accepting it, since it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems by the stack trace - the below part of it - that the class `Message` is being missed.

> Uncaught Error: Class 'google\appengine\api\mail\Message' not found in /home/project/billingemails/index.php:39

For this reason, please, be sure that you have this class well written and in the right folder, so your `index.php` file can call it correctly and send the email as intended. After this class is in the right place, you should be fine.